# Convert a sequence of maps to a map of maps using the value of key in each map

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence that looks like this: `({:a 1 :b "lorem"} {:a 2 :b "ipsum"})` and I want to convert that to a map of maps using the value of `:a` as the value of the key in the new map. The result I am expecting is `{:1 {:a 1 :b "lorem"} :2 {:a 2 :b "ipsum"}}`.

And maybe this is not idiomatic clojure, I'm still learning. I basically receive a large sequence, and I will be looking up values in this sequence by a certain value in each map, and I want to use a map to make it O(1).

In C#, on an `IEnumerable`, you can call `.ToDictionary(x => x.SomeProperty)` which would return a Dictionary of key value pairs, using the value of `SomeProperty` as the key. And this has lookup performance of O(1) instead of the typical O(N) for a list/sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the transform you are after:

```
(def latin '({:a 1 :b "lorem"} {:a 2 :b "ipsum"}))

(defn transform [kw in]
  (zipmap (map kw in) in))

=> (transform :a latin)
{1 {:a 1, :b "lorem"}, 2 {:a 2, :b "ipsum"}}
```

I hesitated in changing the number to a keyword, as not sure as to the reason you would want to do that...

... **edit** - because you can always do an indexed (O(1)) retrieve like so:

```
(get (transform :a latin) 1)
```

`1` doesn't work at the front because it can't be used as a function (unlike `:1`), however `get` is a function whose second argument is the search key when the first argument is a map.

Comment: I actually do want it to be a keyword since (1 result) throws an exception where result is the result from the call to transform. Unless there is a different way to lookup from a map using a long instead of a keyword

Comment: Can you really get keywords that are numbers like that? `(keyword 'a)` gives `:a` as expected, but `(keyword '1)` returns `nil`. You should be able to lookup using any immutable value, so a number no different to any other value.

Comment: I changed it to ``(zipmap (map (comp keyword str kw) in) in))`` which worked for me. Luckily my data will always have strings for the value instead of numbers.

Comment: Good to know about  ``keyword`` returning nil for a numeric value. I didn't know that.

Comment: Good solution with `comp`. `1` doesn't work well as a function - hence the exception. Just out of interest, it could still be used, for example: `(filter (fn [[k v]] (= k 1))  (transform :a latin))` does not throw an exception.

Comment: Just to be clear, the answer to my question above is that there's no problem having `:1` as a keyword, its just that the `keyword` function likes a string as input, so you can get `:1` using `(keyword (str 1))`.

Comment: Wouldn't using ``filter`` be O(n)? And that would defeat the purpose of using a map which can lookup in O(1).

Comment: Yes bad for performance, unlike your solution. Numbers can be well used as keys in maps sometimes, like when sorting. Gone completely off-topic...